# How to best address the adverse impact of SSL encryption on zero-copy optimization

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

Kafka consumers are unable to take advantage of zero-copy optimization over SSL encryption. This is because SSL requires copying of data for encryption before sending it over the wire. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Other than installing Kafka on machines with more CPU space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to have end-to-end encryption so that broker always deals with encrypted messages thereby still taking advantage of zero-copy. 
Encrypt while producing and decrypt while consuming - if the kafka producer and consumer apis can do this out of box (with support to get keys per topic/cluster) this can be achieved. This is under discussion at [KIP-317](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-317%3A+Add+end-to-end+data+encryption+functionality+to+Apache+Kafka)

Alternatively you can have side cars that do this transparently for you. Check out [this](https://medium.com/jayanthg/transparently-securing-kafka-istio-style-with-up-to-300-higher-performance-than-native-tls-in-aa95731b5d40) interesting blog which uses side-cars to achieve the same.